# How to remove or change icons in gnome-terminal 3.18.3?

Tags: 16.04, gnome, icons, gnome-terminal, gtk

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 and am trying to (i) ideally remove, or (ii) change the clunky look of, the "plus sign" and "dropdown arrow" near the tabs of `gnome-terminal`.

The red box in the following image shows the icons:

[image: clunky]

Any tips on how to remove these icons? Can their styles be modified in `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`? Can alternative icons be used?

Comment: You upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04? Are you using unity or gnome-shell?

Comment: @Anwar I am using Unity, and 16.04 is a fresh install.

Comment: Have you installed any other desktop environment before like mate, lxde or cinnamon?

Comment: @Anwar I have not installed any other such desktop environment.

Comment: I think you can't do much without changing Icon themes. I have some suggestion for you in an answer. check them out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately those icons are from default **Ubuntu Mono Dark** icon theme. I fear you can't do much without replacing those icons or using other Icon theme.

Here are some alternatives I want to suggest you to try.

1. Mate Faenza Dark icon theme (Most preferable)

   [image: mate faenza dark]
2. Revival Icon theme

   [image: revival]
3. MacBuntu OS Icon theme

   [image: macbuntu os icon theme]
4. Paper Icon theme

   [image: paper icon theme with Ambiance]

You should be able to find the icon theme from various PPAs available. Some of them are

- [Noobslab Icon Collection](https://launchpad.net/~noobslab/+archive/ubuntu/icons)
- [Noobslab Icon Collection 2](https://launchpad.net/~noobslab/+archive/ubuntu/icons2)
- [MacBuntu by Noobslab](https://launchpad.net/~noobslab/+archive/ubuntu/macbuntu)
- [Noobslab Master Page](https://launchpad.net/~noobslab)

Comment: @jesterII Glad that helped :) There are lots of them. Try some. you'll find many good icons i think. good luck!